# omxplayer-git won't compile on archlinux

Tags: archlinux, video

I'm trying to create a omxplayer package from [AUR](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages.php?ID=59770). But it can't compile (via `makepkg`) but gives me this:

```
SubtitleRenderer.cpp: In member function 'void SubtitleRenderer::initialize_window(int)':
SubtitleRenderer.cpp:368:3: error: 'graphics_get_display_size' was not declared in this scope
make: *** [SubtitleRenderer.o] Error 1
```

From glancing at the error message it seems like a simple bug in the source. But I can't find anyone else complaining (though the last push to the git repository was a few months from now). So I believe the problem is at my end.

Comment: i have the same issue ... help anyone? EDIT: i informed the packager on the AUR page, maybe he can help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding a forgotten include omxplayer now compiles. The git repository is updated. I suppose I could thank @ap0 for getting in touch with the author.

I just removed the build-directory and started from scratch and it compiled just fine.

Edit: If you care about scores on this site you might create your own answer (which says about the same as this) and I will gladly score and accept it.

Comment: Regardless of score, a correctly marked answer makes it easier for searchers to find what they are looking for :)